# How to calculate the size of the container in which the elements are positioned absolutely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container in which there are div-elements with absolute positioning. How can I calculate the size of the container?
Here is an example as it is now working. (dimensions are calculated is not correct):

```
var container = $("#container");
var inc=0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var div = $("<div/>");
    div.css("left", (100 * i + inc));
    container.append(div);
    inc+=3;
}

$("body").append("<span>SIZE CONTAINER: "+ container.width()+"</span>");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/udj71yyx/

Option enumeration of all elements as: size = width * lastIndex. Not suitable. Thank U!

Answer (score 1):

As you made your child element `position:absolute` you wont get the correct `width`.

Here is a another way, that will give you a proper width that you actually looking for,

```
var container = $("#container");
var width = 0;
var inc=0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var div = $("<div/>");
    div.css("left", (100 * i + inc));
    container.append(div);
    inc+=3;
    width = width + $("#container div").eq(i).width();
}

$("body").append("<span>SIZE CONTAINER: "+ width +"</span>");
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/udj71yyx/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop('scrollWidth')` for this.

```
$("body").append("<span>SIZE CONTAINER: "+ container.prop('scrollWidth')+"</span>");
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/prashant_ghimire/9r4wuubL/1/)

Comment: This solution does not fit, I wrote about it above. I have this function is performed every 15 seconds, adding to this value window.width / 2. To the latter was in the center of the element. This is done every 15 seconds because the new divs appear dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

check updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/udj71yyx/5/) . calculate width of div added to container.

```
var container = $("#container");
var inc=0;
var wdith = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var div = $("<div/>");
  div.css("left", (100 * i + inc));
  container.append(div);
  console.log(div.width());
  wdith += div.width();
  inc+=3;
 }
 $("body").append("<span>SIZE CONTAINER: "+wdith+"</span>");
```

Comment: This solution does not fit, I wrote about it above. I have this function is performed every 15 seconds, adding to this value window.width / 2. To the latter was in the center of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the child `divs` in the `#container`, and use `getBoundingClientRect()` - the largest right value will be the width if the `#container`.

```js
var container = $("#container");
var inc=0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var div = $("<div/>");
    div.css("left", (100 * i + inc));
    container.append(div);
    inc+=3;
}

var cont = document.getElementById('container'), 
    select = cont.querySelectorAll('div'), 
    select = Array.prototype.slice.call(select), 
    totalWidth = 0; 

select.forEach(function(node) {  
    if (totalWidth < node.getBoundingClientRect().right) {
        totalWidth = node.getBoundingClientRect().right; 
    }
}); 

$("body").append("<span>SIZE CONTAINER: " + totalWidth +"</span>");
```

```css
#container div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:black;
    position:absolute;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}

span{ position:relative;   top:300px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Hello! thanks for the reply. The solution works is not entirely correct. if, for example add a button that will take the width and click on it in the middle of the document, the size is wrong Calculate.